# mysql_query or (why no echo here?)

Tags: php, mysql

Why is it not ok to do a echo after the mysql_query or?

so `mysql_query or die ("error")` is legit but why `mysql_query or echo ("error")` not?

Is there any other possibility to print text (or maybe fill a variable) without exiting the whole following code?

Comment: 1. dont use mysql but mysqli or pdo 2. what kind of text do you need to print? You cant print it before or inside die?

Comment: Be careful with the OR statement. Keep in mind that you should rather check if the query is done rather than giving it an opportunity to don't do it (also, avoid mysql_*, since it's deprecated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `or` you can use either; `die("error")` or `print("error")`. It would be much better if you did something like the following, as it would allow you to;

- Log the error
- Report the error to your developers
- Kill the page appropriately (maybe redirect to a page set-up to handle status code 500)

<code_me_up_batman>

```
$obj = mysql_query("select * from table", $link);
if(mysql_error($link)) {
   echo "Error";
   //Log the error?
   die;
}
```

Please note;

> The mysql_ extension is **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Typically errors from MySQL are logged in the error.log depending on how your server is setup without having to take the extra step. YMMV

Comment: @JayBlanchard Which error.log? I've never seen/heard/experienced this before. What's the meaning of YMMV? :)

Comment: If you're on a Linux machine look at the error log for your server. On many Linux distros the path is /var/log/apache/error.log. YMMV == 'Your mileage may vary'

Comment: Ah, great info, thanks! (and thanks for the edit, haha c&p oversight)

Comment: I changed everything to MySQLi. I used array_push to collect all Error Messages and show them after.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have good answers, but something that I do is like this (except I use PDO now, as should you):

```
function error_catcher( $error ) {
    // Any code you want here, including echo, logging, emailing of error, and so on.
}

$sql=mysql_query("select * from table") or die(error_catcher(mysql_error()));
```

Please note:

> The mysql_ extension is **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score -1):

Simple run the mysql_query, and then you can access the `mysql_errno` or `mysql_error`.
And use mysqli function instead mysql_ functions.